# ElastiCache Memory Usage does not balance in Cluster mode

Tags: redis, amazon-elasticache, redis-cluster

ElastiCache version 5.0.6

Shards: 3

Nodes: 3

Cluster Mode: ENABLED

Had perform Shard Rebalancing but still only 1 shard usage is high instead of 3 shard.

[The Redis memory usage inbalance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9pUZA.png)

Expected 3 shards memory to be running in balance.

Answer (score 0):

There can be a number of causes for this behavior. Here are some typical elements to think about and actions to take:

**Key Distribution**: ElastiCache uses a hash of keys to store data from Redis shards. Uneven shard utilization may result from skewed data access patterns, where some keys are used substantially more frequently than others. Take a look at the key distribution and data access patterns in your application. Design your application to spread data among keys more equitably, if at all possible.

**Cache Affinity**: Uneven shard consumption may result from your application's cache affinity, in which some keys are more frequently visited together. Redis stores similar keys on the same shard, which causes this to occur. If your data model or application logic is creating uneven shard consumption, think about optimizing it to lower cache affinity.

**ElastiCache for Redis's** shard rebalancing operation does not happen instantly. It happens automatically and gradually in the background. It could take some time for the cluster to reach a balanced state, depending on the volume of data and the patterns of access. To determine if shard use balance improves over time, you can keep an eye on the cluster's condition.

**Cluster Configuration**: Verify that the cluster is set up with the appropriate number of nodes and shards. You should have a total of nine nodes if you configured three shards with three nodes each. Make sure that each node is sound and linked to the cluster correctly.

**Memory and Eviction Policies**: Verify whether the heavily used shard is under memory stress and is subject to a lot of evictions. A shard may experience an increased burden if it is forced to evict data often because of memory constraints. You could have to change the eviction rules, and the cache size, or think about utilizing bigger instance types.

**Monitoring and Metrics**: To understand the cluster's activity, make use of ElastiCache's monitoring and CloudWatch metrics. On each individual shard, look for metrics for CPU, RAM, and cache hits and misses. This information can be used to locate performance bottlenecks.

When writing data to the cache, take your data distribution plan into account. Make sure that keys are dispersed among the available shards as equally as possible if you are utilizing consistent hashing. A small subset of keys dominating a shard should be avoided.

**Considerations for Scaling**: In order to handle the workload more efficiently, you may need to extend your ElastiCache cluster by adding more shards or nodes, depending on your use case and traffic patterns.

**Cache segmentation**: To more evenly distribute the workload, you might occasionally need to divide your cache data among several ElastiCache clusters.

Answer (score -1):

I believe intention of this question is to ask possible debugging steps and arriving possible solutions. Based on this , these suggestions would be helpful.

Possible Debugging Procedures:

1. Check if keys are not getting distributed evenly.
   Please check hashslot for keys that lies in higher memory shard. Redis uses the Hash slot-based sharding technique.If it is due to the key's inherent pattern, you can consider defining your own sharding logic to distribute keys evenly. You can think of a consistent hashing algorithm as alternative.

   Look for **Redis Cluster data sharding** under link -
   https://redis.io/docs/management/scaling/ for Redis sharding
   techniques.
2. Check value sizes that are stored in higher memory shared. There could be the reason that data which are stored in higher memory shard is of high memory size and due to which memory imbalance is happening.
3. You can manually migrate particular keys from one shard to another in a controlled manner. Redis tooling such as **Migrate** would be helpful in such cases. https://redis.io/commands/migrate/
4. If memory imbalance is still there as a persistent problem, you can consider scaling the cluster either vertically (by increasing the instance's memory) or horizontally (by adding more shards). Scaling horizontally can be particularly helpful for evenly distributing data.